# What are the downsides of making a numeric column a string in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have members on my team who are tossing around the idea to make every column in the database a string including numeric columns.

I know that sorting becomes an issue and data integrity becomes an issue and performance becomes and issue.

What are the other downsides of making a numeric column a string just for edification and so I can share with the team members?

Comment: For example, all mathematics goes with wind  select '23'-'45'

Comment: Int comparisons are faster than varchar comparisons, for the simple fact that ints take up much less space than varchars.

Comment: Are comparisons the only advantage?

Comment: @OsamaBinSaleem . . . For whole numbers less than 1000, ints take up as much or more space space than the string representation.

Comment: BTW, there are some DBMS, like https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-universe-0/rocket-universe, which only use strings to store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major issue is that users can put broken data into the columns -- data that is not numeric.  That is simply not possible with the correct type.  Although you could add a check constraint for every numeric column, that seems like a lot of work.

The scenario is:  You have a query that works and has worked for a long time.  All of a sudden, someone puts a non-numeric value into the column.  The query breaks.  And because the query was (probably) using implicit conversion, it is really hard to tell where the problem is.

Let me just say:  I am speaking from experience here.

Other problems are:

- Comparisons don't work as expected:  `'0' <> '0.0'`.
- Comparisons don't work as expected:  `'9' > '100'`.
- Comparisons don't work as expected: `'.1' < '0.01'`.
- Sorting doesn't work as expected.
- The code is filled with (unnecessary and typically implicit) conversions.
- Some databases, such as SQL Server, overload operators so `'1' + '1' <> '2'`.
- Some databases overload operators, so `current_timestamp + 1` is valid but `current_timestamp + '1'` is invalid.
- A comparison in a query can affect index usage.  So, `strcol = 1` ends up converting `strcol` to a number, which typically precludes the use of an index.  On the other hand, `intcol = '1'` ends up converting the constant to a number, which still allows the index to be used.  **I do not recommend mixing types in comparisons, though.**

Space is a wash, because in many cases the string representation might be smaller than the number representation.  It depends in that case.  There is a slight hit on indexing, because fixed length keys are usually more efficient.

If you mix types, things get worse -- because that affects the optimizer.

Some things that are composed of numbers are not necessarily numeric.  You can usually tell the difference easily:  does it make sense to perform arithmetic operations on the value?  Or another indicator:  do leading zeros make sense?

Comment: This is great, thank you.  So validation, efficiency, calculation, comparison, bloated code, sorting, and more.

Comment: @mutant_city . . . That is a pretty good summary.

Answer (score 3):

- it will take more space
- indexes will also take more space and be less efficient
- ordering will not work correctly (e.g. "10" < "2")
- any numeric operations will not work correctly (e.g. 10% more than x)

having said all this, fields like SSN, phone number, etc. that appear numeric but are not really numbers should be strings.

Comment: But if you use a CAST will the numeric operations and sorting then work?

Comment: yes, but casting is not free. we try to make databases more efficient, right?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if the numeric column is an ID and never used for calculations, it is probably OK. If the numbers are "measures", like amount or quantity, I would not recommend it as you most likely would want to do calculations at some point (like SUM, AVG, etc)

Comment: Does doing a CAST to a numeric allow for those to be treated as numeric?

Comment: Yes, you can convert strings to numeric, however you will get performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I got this type of issue to an externally designed db faced lots of challenges:

1. Conversion of date, numeric columns during querying
2. Indexing took more space and has slower performance